# React Native: How do you enable async functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, native, babeljs

I've read that later versions of RN enable async functions by default, but I'm using 0.28.0 and get an unexpected token error when I try using async or await.  I've tried installing the babel preset for async functions and creating a .babelrc with the proper presets, but that didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  My issue was how I constructed my functions.

Originally I had:

```
async hello: function() {
    return 'hello';
}
```

But What I was suppose to do was:

```
async hello() {
    return 'hello';
}
```

Nothing having to do with Babel...

Also keep in mind that this was for createClass(), not es6 classes.